# cURL curl: (60) SSL certificate: Invalid certificate chain

Tags: curl

1. At home Win7 PC, I just download from here: http://curl.haxx.se/download.html, works perfectly, nothing else need to be done.

   C:\Tools\curl-7.33.0-win64-ssl-sspi>curl https:\www.google.com
   C:\Tools\curl-7.33.0-win64-ssl-sspi>curl https://api.github.com/zen
   Practicality beats purity.
2. But at a company Win7 PC, I tried everything I can find on the web, but still doesn't work.

Any idea why?
Thanks
Jirong

Comment: It looks like a general issue on my company's PC. I am getting the same error with gradlew. Even adding the cert to my java cert store doesn't help. Must be something else with this company PC.

Comment: It turns out our company has a WebSense with a proxy.